# What possible reasons can cause my plugin not to be listed in the plugin search in the back-end of wordpress installs?

Tags: plugins, installation

our plugin is listed on wordpress.org but it can't be found if you go in the backend of a WP install and search for it under Plugins -> Add New.

Our plugin was delisted some time ago from wordpress.org but now it's listed again, why is it not appearing in search results?

This is the body of the all-in-one-event-calendar.php file

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: All-in-One Event Calendar by Timely
 * Plugin URI: http://time.ly/
 * Description: A calendar system with month, week, day, agenda views, upcoming events widget, color-coded categories, recurrence, and import/export of .ics feeds.
 * Author: Timely
 * Author URI: http://time.ly/
 * Version: 1.10
 */
@set_time_limit( 0 );
@ini_set( 'memory_limit',           '256M' );
@ini_set( 'max_input_time',         '-1' );

// ===============
// = Plugin Name =
// ===============
define( 'AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME',        'all-in-one-event-calendar' );

// ===================
// = Plugin Basename =
// ===================
define( 'AI1EC_PLUGIN_BASENAME',    plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );

// ==================
// = Plugin Version =
// ==================
define( 'AI1EC_VERSION',            '1.10' );

// ====================
// = Database Version =
// ====================
define( 'AI1EC_DB_VERSION',         109 );

// ==========================
// = Bundled themes version =
// ==========================
define( 'AI1EC_THEMES_VERSION',     8 );

// ================
// = Cron Version =
// ================
define( 'AI1EC_CRON_VERSION',       104 );
define( 'AI1EC_N_CRON_VERSION',     103 );
define( 'AI1EC_N_CRON_FREQ',        'daily' );
define( 'AI1EC_UPDATES_URL',        'http://time.ly/plugin/standard/latest' );

// ===============
// = Plugin Path =
// ===============
define( 'AI1EC_PATH',               dirname( __FILE__ ) );

// ===================
// = CSS Folder name =
// ===================
define( 'AI1EC_CSS_FOLDER',         'css' );

// ==================
// = JS Folder name =
// ==================
define( 'AI1EC_JS_FOLDER',          'js' );

// =====================
// = Image folder name =
// =====================
define( 'AI1EC_IMG_FOLDER',         'img' );

// ============
// = Lib Path =
// ============
define( 'AI1EC_LIB_PATH',           AI1EC_PATH . '/lib' );

// =================
// = Language Path =
// =================
define( 'AI1EC_LANGUAGE_PATH',      AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME . '/language' );

// ============
// = App Path =
// ============
define( 'AI1EC_APP_PATH',           AI1EC_PATH . '/app' );

// ===================
// = Controller Path =
// ===================
define( 'AI1EC_CONTROLLER_PATH',    AI1EC_APP_PATH . '/controller' );

// ==============
// = Model Path =
// ==============
define( 'AI1EC_MODEL_PATH',         AI1EC_APP_PATH . '/model' );

// =============
// = View Path =
// =============
define( 'AI1EC_VIEW_PATH',          AI1EC_APP_PATH . '/view' );

// ====================
// = Admin Theme Path =
// ====================
define( 'AI1EC_ADMIN_THEME_PATH',   AI1EC_VIEW_PATH . '/admin' );

// ==================
// = Admin theme CSS path =
// ==================
define( 'AI1EC_ADMIN_THEME_CSS_PATH', AI1EC_ADMIN_THEME_PATH . '/' . AI1EC_CSS_FOLDER );

// =======================
// = Admin theme JS path =
// =======================
define( 'AI1EC_ADMIN_THEME_JS_PATH', AI1EC_ADMIN_THEME_PATH . '/' . AI1EC_JS_FOLDER );

// ========================
// = Admin theme IMG path =
// ========================
define( 'AI1EC_ADMIN_THEME_IMG_PATH', AI1EC_ADMIN_THEME_PATH . '/' . AI1EC_IMG_FOLDER );

// ===============
// = Helper Path =
// ===============
define( 'AI1EC_HELPER_PATH',        AI1EC_APP_PATH . '/helper' );

// ==================
// = Exception Path =
// ==================
define( 'AI1EC_EXCEPTION_PATH',     AI1EC_APP_PATH . '/exception' );

// ==============
// = Plugin Url =
// ==============
define( 'AI1EC_URL',                plugins_url( '', __FILE__ ) );

// ==============
// = Images URL =
// ==============
define( 'AI1EC_IMAGE_URL',          AI1EC_URL . '/' . AI1EC_IMG_FOLDER );

// ===========
// = CSS URL =
// ===========
define( 'AI1EC_CSS_URL',            AI1EC_URL . '/' . AI1EC_CSS_FOLDER );

// ==========
// = JS URL =
// ==========
define( 'AI1EC_JS_URL',             AI1EC_URL . '/' . AI1EC_JS_FOLDER );

// ================
// = Admin JS URL =
// ================
define( 'AI1EC_ADMIN_THEME_JS_URL', AI1EC_URL . '/app/view/admin/' . AI1EC_JS_FOLDER );

// =================
// = Admin CSS URL =
// =================
define( 'AI1EC_ADMIN_THEME_CSS_URL', AI1EC_URL . '/app/view/admin/' . AI1EC_CSS_FOLDER );

// =================
// = Admin IMG URL =
// =================
define( 'AI1EC_ADMIN_THEME_IMG_URL', AI1EC_URL . '/app/view/admin/' . AI1EC_IMG_FOLDER );

// =============
// = POST TYPE =
// =============
define( 'AI1EC_POST_TYPE',          'ai1ec_event' );

// =====================================================
// = UPDATE THEMES PAGE BASE URL (wrap in admin_url()) =
// =====================================================
define( 'AI1EC_UPDATE_THEMES_BASE_URL', 'edit.php?post_type=' . AI1EC_POST_TYPE . '&page=' . AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME . '-update-themes' );

// =====================================================
// = FEED SETTINGS PAGE BASE URL (wrap in admin_url()) =
// =====================================================
define( 'AI1EC_FEED_SETTINGS_BASE_URL', 'edit.php?post_type=' . AI1EC_POST_TYPE . '&page=' . AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME . '-feeds' );

// ================================================
// = SETTINGS PAGE BASE URL (wrap in admin_url()) =
// ================================================
define( 'AI1EC_SETTINGS_BASE_URL',  'edit.php?post_type=' . AI1EC_POST_TYPE . '&page=' . AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME . '-settings' );

// ======================
// = Default Theme Name =
// ======================
define( 'AI1EC_DEFAULT_THEME_NAME', 'vortex' );

// =============================
// = Default Theme folder name =
// =============================
define( 'AI1EC_THEMES_FOLDER',      'themes-ai1ec' );

// ========================
// = AI1EC Theme location =
// ========================
define( 'AI1EC_THEMES_ROOT',        WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/' . AI1EC_THEMES_FOLDER );

// ===================
// = AI1EC Theme URL =
// ===================
define( 'AI1EC_THEMES_URL',         WP_CONTENT_URL . '/' . AI1EC_THEMES_FOLDER );

// ======================
// = Default theme path =
// ======================
define( 'AI1EC_DEFAULT_THEME_PATH', AI1EC_THEMES_ROOT . '/' . AI1EC_DEFAULT_THEME_NAME );

// =====================
// = Default theme url =
// =====================
define( 'AI1EC_DEFAULT_THEME_URL',  AI1EC_THEMES_URL . '/' . AI1EC_DEFAULT_THEME_NAME );

// ======================================================
// = INSTALL THEMES PAGE BASE URL (wrap in admin_url()) =
// ======================================================
define( 'AI1EC_INSTALL_THEMES_BASE_URL', 'themes.php?page=' . AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME . '-install-themes' );

// ================
// = RSS FEED URL =
// ================
define( 'AI1EC_RSS_FEED',           'http://time.ly/feed/' );

// ======================================
// = FAKE CATEGORY ID FOR CALENDAR PAGE =
// ======================================
define( 'AI1EC_FAKE_CATEGORY_ID',   -4113473042 ); // Numeric-only 1337-speak of AI1EC_CALENDAR - ID must be numeric

// ==============
// = SCRIPT URL =
// ==============
$ai1ec_script_url = get_option( 'home' ) . '/?plugin=' . AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME;
define( 'AI1EC_SCRIPT_URL',         $ai1ec_script_url );

// ====================================================
// = Convert http:// to webcal:// in AI1EC_SCRIPT_URL =
// =  (webcal:// protocol does not support https://)  =
// ====================================================
$tmp = str_replace( 'http://', 'webcal://', AI1EC_SCRIPT_URL );

// ==============
// = EXPORT URL =
// ==============
define( 'AI1EC_EXPORT_URL',         $tmp . "&controller=ai1ec_exporter_controller&action=export_events&cb=" . rand() );

// ====================================
// = Include iCal parsers and helpers =
// ====================================
if( version_compare( PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0' ) >= 0 ) {
    // Parser that requires PHP v5.3.0 or up
    require_once( AI1EC_LIB_PATH . '/iCalcreator-2.14/iCalcreator.class.php' );
} else {
    // Parser that works on PHP versions below 5.3.0
    require_once( AI1EC_LIB_PATH . '/iCalcreator-2.10/iCalcreator.class.php' );
    require_once( AI1EC_LIB_PATH . '/iCalcreator-2.10/iCalUtilityFunctions.class.php' );
}
require_once( AI1EC_LIB_PATH . '/SG_iCal.php' );
require_once( AI1EC_LIB_PATH . '/helpers/SG_iCal_Line.php' );
require_once( AI1EC_LIB_PATH . '/helpers/SG_iCal_Duration.php' );
require_once( AI1EC_LIB_PATH . '/helpers/SG_iCal_Freq.php' );
require_once( AI1EC_LIB_PATH . '/helpers/SG_iCal_Recurrence.php' );
require_once( AI1EC_LIB_PATH . '/helpers/SG_iCal_Parser.php' );
require_once( AI1EC_LIB_PATH . '/helpers/SG_iCal_Query.php' );
require_once( AI1EC_LIB_PATH . '/helpers/SG_iCal_Factory.php' );
// include our global functions
require_once( AI1EC_LIB_PATH . '/global-functions.php' );

// ===============================
// = The autoload function =
// ===============================
function ai1ec_autoload( $class_name )
{
    // Convert class name to filename format.
    $class_name = strtr( strtolower( $class_name ), '_', '-' );
    $paths = array(
        AI1EC_CONTROLLER_PATH,
        AI1EC_MODEL_PATH,
        AI1EC_HELPER_PATH,
        AI1EC_EXCEPTION_PATH,
        AI1EC_LIB_PATH,
        AI1EC_VIEW_PATH,
        AI1EC_ADMIN_THEME_PATH,
        get_option( 'ai1ec_current_theme_path', AI1EC_DEFAULT_THEME_PATH ),
        AI1EC_DEFAULT_THEME_PATH
    );

    // remove duplicates from the paths array
    $paths = array_unique( $paths );

    // Search each path for the class.
    foreach( $paths as $path ) {
        if( file_exists( "$path/class-$class_name.php" ) )
            require_once( "$path/class-$class_name.php" );
    }
}
spl_autoload_register( 'ai1ec_autoload' );

// ===============================
// = Initialize and setup MODELS =
// ===============================
global $ai1ec_settings;

$ai1ec_settings = Ai1ec_Settings::get_instance();


// ================================
// = Initialize and setup HELPERS =
// ================================
global $ai1ec_view_helper,
       $ai1ec_settings_helper,
       $ai1ec_calendar_helper,
       $ai1ec_app_helper,
       $ai1ec_events_helper,
       $ai1ec_importer_helper,
       $ai1ec_exporter_helper;

$ai1ec_view_helper     = Ai1ec_View_Helper::get_instance();
$ai1ec_settings_helper = Ai1ec_Settings_Helper::get_instance();
$ai1ec_calendar_helper = Ai1ec_Calendar_Helper::get_instance();
$ai1ec_app_helper      = Ai1ec_App_Helper::get_instance();
$ai1ec_events_helper   = Ai1ec_Events_Helper::get_instance();
$ai1ec_importer_helper = Ai1ec_Importer_Helper::get_instance();
$ai1ec_exporter_helper = Ai1ec_Exporter_Helper::get_instance();

// ====================================
// = Initialize and setup CONTROLLERS =
// ====================================
global $ai1ec_app_controller,
       $ai1ec_settings_controller,
       $ai1ec_events_controller,
       $ai1ec_calendar_controller,
       $ai1ec_importer_controller,
       $ai1ec_exporter_controller,
       $ai1ec_themes_controller;

$ai1ec_settings_controller  = Ai1ec_Settings_Controller::get_instance();
$ai1ec_events_controller    = Ai1ec_Events_Controller::get_instance();
$ai1ec_calendar_controller  = Ai1ec_Calendar_Controller::get_instance();
$ai1ec_importer_controller  = Ai1ec_Importer_Controller::get_instance();
$ai1ec_exporter_controller  = Ai1ec_Exporter_Controller::get_instance();
$ai1ec_themes_controller    = Ai1ec_Themes_Controller::get_instance();

// ==========================================================================
// = All app initialization is done in Ai1ec_App_Controller::__construct(). =
// ==========================================================================
$ai1ec_app_controller      = Ai1ec_App_Controller::get_instance();
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the code.

Comment: @toscho what code do you need?The boostrap file?

Comment: Yes, the main plugin file with the headers. Also make sure there are no othe PHP files in the main directory.

Comment: @toscho i'll copy/paste the code in the question, but how can't we not have other files?What about uninstall.php?

Comment: Okay, that might be an exception. Make sure none of the other files start with something that could be read as a plugin header.

Comment: @toscho i added the file

Comment: @toscho and this is the link on wordpress. org http://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar/

Comment: It _could be_ the line `// = Plugin Name =`. Try removing that (it is not a proper doc block anyway), and see if the plugin shows up.

Comment: @toscho i'll try this and i'll let you know what happens.

Comment: what are you searching for exactly? I can find it by searching the name. I noticed you don't have any tags associated with the plugin.

Comment: @Milo you are right i was searching for "Calendar", we have tags associated with it, maybe we are doing something worng http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/ical-feed